# Making the Post/Page Content Editor Box Bigger?

Tags: editor

I'm having difficulty in creating a big post since the editor box is quite small. I want to make it bigger. Can I?

Comment: Are you complaining about the same problem as me? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2067/why-is-the-visual-editor-in-wordpress-limiting-the-width-by-wrapping-the-content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a couple of options. First, you can always click on the bottom right corner of the post edit box and drag to resize:

[image]

However, you can also make it so that the post box is larger by default. Go to Settings > Writing, and change the value for size of the post box:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also click on the blue square icon, second from right in your screenshot. That brings the edit box to full screen.