# Can't change the width of content in the visual editor

Tags: visual-editor

I'm using a child of Twentyfourteen on [this site](http://www.kensingtonmn.com) (although I'm not sure that the theme being used is relevant in this case).

The content of the visual editor is being set by this style rule:

```
html .mceContentBody {
    font-size: 100%;
    max-width: 474px;
}
```

I followed the answer in this question: ["Why is the visual editor in WordPress limiting the width by wrapping the content?"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2067/why-is-the-visual-editor-in-wordpress-limiting-the-width-by-wrapping-the-content) and put this code in my custom editor stylesheet:

```
html .mceContentBody {
    max-width: none !important; }
```

I am quite positive I'm correctly enqueuing the custom editor stylesheet (changes I make in style.css work). Here's what I have in my child functions.php file:

```
<?php

function RegisterCustomScriptsStyles(){
  // Register and enqueue custom stylesheets

  // Register custom stylesheets to the path to the theme's stylesheets
  wp_register_style( 'customStylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
  wp_register_style( 'customEditorStylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/editor-style.css');

  // Enqueue the stylesheets
  wp_enqueue_style( 'customStylesheet' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'customEditorStylesheet' );

  // Register and enqueue custom scripts
  // Register custom scripts to the path to the theme's scripts
  //wp_register_script( 'customScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/customScript.js', array('jquery') );
  //wp_enqueue_script( 'customScript' );
} 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'RegisterCustomScriptsStyles');
```

So what am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress will not know that you want this css applied to the backend unless you load it properly. I believe your css will have loaded on the frontend of the site, but not the backend.

If you want it to load on the backend, you should use instead:

```
function i_want_a_cool_editor_style() {
add_editor_style( 'editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'i_want_a_cool_editor_style' );
```

An alternative approach, if you only have a few styles to load, is to load the css directly on the functions.php (but again, using the right code to load it), eg.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_cool_stylin');

function my_cool_stylin() {
 echo '<style>
html .mceContentBody {
  max-width: none !important; }
</style>';
}
```